# I have long name how to show all height of div where it is?

Tags: html, css

I have listed items.

```
     <div layout="column"  class="md-whiteframe-1dp capitalize itemsInList" ng-if="vm.getElementHeight(child.id) > vm.minBoxHeight"  ng-repeat="item in child.work_items " id={{item.id}}child>
        <div layout="row"  layout-align="space-between">
            <div class="workItemName">{{vm.getWorkItemName(item.metadata)}}</div>
            <div>
                <md-icon class="itemEditIcon" ng-click="vm.openItemEdit(item)" md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-edit"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and scss:

```
.itemsInList {
  background-color: $white;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $alto;
  color: $shuttleGray;
}
.workItemName {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

"Extra Long Item..."
have 3 rows of text.
But as you can see on img - it is shown just 2.
[image]

How to show all height of div with text which is inside of it?

[image]

Comment: Set the height to auto? You're not showing us any CSS, so it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: Why dnt you show us your code , it hard to tell without code

Comment: I would remove the height and set it to auto. However, if it would still not work, you could use: display: inline-block

Comment: I've updated the code with css 
tried with display: inline-block  but as you can see - still have the same issue.

Comment: fixed. Hansel F. - helped with inline block. Placed in 'ItemsInList' class.
thanks!!